# FFmpeg RTSP crash

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, rtsp

I am trying to rtsp stream between two consoles on my computer.

On console 1 I have:

```
ffmpeg -rtbufsize 100M -re -f dshow -s 320x240 -i video="BisonCam, NB Pro" -r 10 -an -f rtsp -rtsp_transport tcp rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/demo
```

On console 2 I have:

```
ffplay -rtsp_flags listen -i rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/demo
```

When I run execute both commands, my webcam LED lights up. But then immediately after ffmpeg crashes. Has anyone encountered the same thing? I could really use some help here.

This is my ffmpeg configuration on a Windows 10 machine:

```
ffmpeg version N-81391-g2a3720b Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-libebur128 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 29.100 / 55. 29.100
  libavcodec     57. 54.100 / 57. 54.100
  libavformat    57. 47.101 / 57. 47.101
  libavdevice    57.  0.102 / 57.  0.102
  libavfilter     6. 52.100 /  6. 52.100
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
usage: ffmpeg [options] [[infile options] -i infile]... {[outfile options] outfile}...

Use -h to get full help or, even better, run 'man ffmpeg'
```

**Update**

I tried to stream from a video file, just to be sure that the issue is not related to the webcam.

```
#Console 1
ffmpeg -i out.mp4 -f rtsp -rtsp_transport tcp rtsp://localhost:8888/live.sdp

#Console 2
ffplay -rtsp_flags listen rtsp://localhost:8888/live.sdp?tcp
```

The output for both consoles are as follows:

Console 1:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'out.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.47.101
  Duration: 00:01:02.57, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 172 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High 4:2:2) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv422p, 320x240, 169 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 10000k tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
[rtsp @ 00000000024c1700] Using AVStream.codec to pass codec parameters to muxers is deprecated, use AVStream.codecpar instead.
Output #0, rtsp, to 'rtsp://localhost:8888/live.sdp':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.47.101
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: mpeg4, yuv420p, 320x240, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 30 fps, 90k tbn, 30 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : Lavc57.54.100 mpeg4
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> mpeg4 (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
```

Console 2:

```
[rtsp @ 00000000001ccde0] WARNING: Path /live.sdp differs from expected /live.sdp?tcp
    Last message repeated 1 times
[rtsp @ 00000000001ccde0] Updating control URI to rtsp://localhost:8888/live.sdp
[rtsp @ 00000000001ccde0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile), none, 320x240 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3]): unspecified pixel format
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://localhost:8888/live.sdp?tcp':
  Metadata:
    title           : No Name
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile), none, 320x240 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 30 tbc
    nan M-V:    nan fd=   0 aq=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0
```

The same crash happened with ffmpeg.exe, and ffplay continued waiting for data. I tried the same commands on a Linux virtual machine, and it worked fine.

Any ideas?

**Update**

Here's what I've got from gdb:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'out.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.47.101
  Duration: 00:01:02.57, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 172 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High 4:2:2) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv422p, 320x240, 169 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 10000k tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
[New Thread 15408.0x3f28]
[New Thread 15408.0x86c]
[New Thread 15408.0x23c8]
[New Thread 15408.0xf48]
[New Thread 15408.0x354c]
[New Thread 15408.0xf24]
[New Thread 15408.0x1e4c]
[New Thread 15408.0x257c]
[New Thread 15408.0x22a4]
[New Thread 15408.0xc88]
[New Thread 15408.0x40bc]
[New Thread 15408.0x1520]
[New Thread 15408.0x2584]
[New Thread 15408.0x1a64]
[New Thread 15408.0x3934]
[New Thread 15408.0x4010]
[New Thread 15408.0x3d28]
[New Thread 15408.0x288c]
[New Thread 15408.0x1e50]
[New Thread 15408.0x630]
[New Thread 15408.0x4128]
[New Thread 15408.0x3fa0]
[New Thread 15408.0x20ec]
[New Thread 15408.0x4bcc]
[New Thread 15408.0x17b4]
[New Thread 15408.0x1204]
[New Thread 15408.0x2dc8]
[rtsp @ 0000000000e458e0] Using AVStream.codec to pass codec parameters to muxers is deprecated, use AVStream.codecpar instead.
[New Thread 15408.0x1d14]
Output #0, rtsp, to 'rtsp://localhost:8888/live.sdp':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.47.101
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: mpeg4, yuv420p, 320x240, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 30 fps, 90k tbn, 30 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : Lavc57.54.100 mpeg4
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> mpeg4 (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ff82d95292f in avpriv_mpegts_parse_close () from E:\Dev\Library\ffmpeg-20160819-2a3720b-win64-shared\bin\avformat-57.dll
```

And the backtrace:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ff82d95292f in avpriv_mpegts_parse_close () from E:\Dev\Library\ffmpeg-20160819-2a3720b-win64-shared\bin\avformat-57.dll
#1  0x00007ff82d956a1b in avformat-57!av_get_output_timestamp () from E:\Dev\Library\ffmpeg-20160819-2a3720b-win64-shared\bin\avformat-57.dll
#2  0x00007ff82d9a5dbe in ff_rtsp_parse_line () from E:\Dev\Library\ffmpeg-20160819-2a3720b-win64-shared\bin\avformat-57.dll
#3  0x00007ff82d955e6d in avformat-57!av_interleaved_write_frame () from E:\Dev\Library\ffmpeg-20160819-2a3720b-win64-shared\bin\avformat-57.dll
#4  0x000000014001af78 in ?? ()
#5  0x000000014001bda9 in ?? ()
#6  0x000000014001e642 in ?? ()
#7  0x00000001400201f1 in ?? ()
#8  0x000000014004bd47 in ?? ()
#9  0x00000001400013ed in ?? ()
#10 0x000000014000152b in ?? ()
#11 0x00007ff85e2b8102 in KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk () from C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
#12 0x00007ff85edac264 in ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#13 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame inner to this frame (corrupt stack?)
(gdb)
```

**Update 2**

Here's using ffmpeg_g.exe

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'out.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.47.101
  Duration: 00:01:02.57, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 172 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High 4:2:2) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv422p, 320x240, 169 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 10000k tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
[New Thread 14052.0x3560]
[New Thread 14052.0x24b4]
[New Thread 14052.0x3554]
[New Thread 14052.0x1a3c]
[New Thread 14052.0x2e64]
[New Thread 14052.0xd0c]
[New Thread 14052.0x29e4]
[New Thread 14052.0x3724]
[New Thread 14052.0x36f8]
[New Thread 14052.0x36f0]
[New Thread 14052.0x78]
[New Thread 14052.0x1578]
[New Thread 14052.0x36a0]
[New Thread 14052.0x3688]
[New Thread 14052.0x369c]
[New Thread 14052.0x1f84]
[New Thread 14052.0x2094]
[New Thread 14052.0x2f14]
[New Thread 14052.0x2c54]
[New Thread 14052.0x3624]
[New Thread 14052.0x2d44]
[New Thread 14052.0x3424]
[New Thread 14052.0x1dd4]
[New Thread 14052.0x20c4]
[New Thread 14052.0x34d8]
[New Thread 14052.0x34e4]
[New Thread 14052.0x3528]
[rtsp @ 0000000000f75a80] Using AVStream.codec to pass codec parameters to muxers is deprecated, use AVStream.codecpar instead.
[New Thread 14052.0x3564]
Output #0, rtsp, to 'rtsp://localhost:8888/live.sdp':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.47.101
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: mpeg4, yuv420p, 320x240, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 30 fps, 90k tbn, 30 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : Lavc57.54.100 mpeg4
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> mpeg4 (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffeecd8292f in avpriv_mpegts_parse_close ()
   from E:\Dev\Library\ffmpeg-20160819-2a3720b-win64-shared\bin\avformat-57.dll
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffeecd8292f in avpriv_mpegts_parse_close ()
   from E:\Dev\Library\ffmpeg-20160819-2a3720b-win64-shared\bin\avformat-57.dll
#1  0x00007ffeecd86a1b in avformat-57!av_get_output_timestamp ()
   from E:\Dev\Library\ffmpeg-20160819-2a3720b-win64-shared\bin\avformat-57.dll
#2  0x00007ffeecdd5dbe in ff_rtsp_parse_line ()
   from E:\Dev\Library\ffmpeg-20160819-2a3720b-win64-shared\bin\avformat-57.dll
#3  0x00007ffeecd85e6d in avformat-57!av_interleaved_write_frame
    ()
   from E:\Dev\Library\ffmpeg-20160819-2a3720b-win64-shared\bin\avformat-57.dll
#4  0x000000014001af78 in ?? ()
#5  0x000000014001bda9 in ?? ()
#6  0x000000014001e642 in ?? ()
#7  0x00000001400201f1 in ?? ()
#8  0x000000014004bd47 in ?? ()
#9  0x00000001400013ed in ?? ()
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
```

**Update 3**

After building my own ffmpeg using the `--enable-debug` flag, I'm back at it again. Still getting the same error though. Any ideas? At this point, it seems like there's something wrong with my computer settings.

```
ffmpeg version N-81392-ga453bbb Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.3.1 (GCC) 20160211
  configuration: --prefix=/home/ytan/Dev/build-mingw/ffmpeg/ --enable-cross-compile --cross-prefix=x86_64-w64-mingw32- --arch=x86_64 --target-os=mingw64 --pkg-config-flags=--static --enable-shared --disable-static --enable-libvpx --enable-libvorbis --enable-libmp3lame --enable-openssl --enable-pic --enable-debug --extra-ldlibflags='-static -pthread'
  libavutil      55. 29.100 / 55. 29.100
  libavcodec     57. 54.100 / 57. 54.100
  libavformat    57. 47.101 / 57. 47.101
  libavdevice    57.  0.102 / 57.  0.102
  libavfilter     6. 52.100 /  6. 52.100
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
[New Thread 6352.0x1e6c]
[New Thread 6352.0x12fc]
[New Thread 6352.0x1f70]
[New Thread 6352.0x17b0]
[New Thread 6352.0xdac]
Input #0, dshow, from 'video=BisonCam, NB Pro':
  Duration: N/A, start: 377578.440000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (YUY2 / 0x32595559), yuyv422, 320x240, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 10000k tbn, 10000k tbc
[New Thread 6352.0x544]
[New Thread 6352.0x1d00]
[New Thread 6352.0x1f14]
[New Thread 6352.0x1bb0]
[New Thread 6352.0xf08]
[New Thread 6352.0x7c8]
[New Thread 6352.0x12d0]
[New Thread 6352.0x504]
[New Thread 6352.0x1a74]
[libvpx @ 0000000002f0dc40] v1.6.0-384-g4a25b59
[rtsp @ 0000000002f0aac0] Using AVStream.codec to pass codec parameters to muxers is deprecated, use AVStream.codecpar instead.
[New Thread 6352.0x11dc]
Output #0, rtsp, to 'rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/demo':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.47.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: vp8 (libvpx), yuv420p, 320x240, q=-1--1, 100 kb/s, 10 fps, 90k tbn, 10 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.54.100 libvpx
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> vp8 (libvpx))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ff894fd08af in avpriv_mpegts_parse_close () from E:\Dev\Library\ffmpeg\bin\avformat-57.dll
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ff894fd08af in avpriv_mpegts_parse_close () from E:\Dev\Library\ffmpeg\bin\avformat-57.dll
#1  0x00007ff894fd499b in avformat-57!av_get_output_timestamp () from E:\Dev\Library\ffmpeg\bin\avformat-57.dll
#2  0x00007ff89502dbae in ff_rtsp_parse_line () from E:\Dev\Library\ffmpeg\bin\avformat-57.dll
#3  0x00007ff894fd3ded in avformat-57!av_interleaved_write_frame () from E:\Dev\Library\ffmpeg\bin\avformat-57.dll
#4  0x000000014001ab18 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame inner to this frame (corrupt stack?)
(gdb) thread apply all bt

Thread 19 (Thread 6352.0x11dc):
#0  0x00007ff8c4804e74 in ntdll!ZwRemoveIoCompletion () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#1  0x00007ff8c0663e49 in Tcpip4_WSHStringToAddress () from C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
#2  0x00007ff8c3e58102 in KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk () from C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
#3  0x00007ff8c47bc264 in ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#4  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame inner to this frame (corrupt stack?)

Thread 18 (Thread 6352.0x1a74):
#0  0x00007ff8c4808404 in ntdll!ZwWaitForAlertByThreadId () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#1  0x00007ff8c47c7810 in ntdll!RtlSleepConditionVariableCS () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#2  0x00007ff8c0e2bb47 in SleepConditionVariableCS () from C:\Windows\system32\KernelBase.dll
#3  0x00007ff896f59420 in avfilter_graph_parse_ptr () from E:\Dev\Library\ffmpeg\bin\avfilter-6.dll
#4  0x00007ff896f5935f in avfilter_graph_parse_ptr () from E:\Dev\Library\ffmpeg\bin\avfilter-6.dll
#5  0x00007ff8c38ab097 in msvcrt!_beginthreadex () from C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
#6  0x00007ff8c38ab16c in msvcrt!_endthreadex () from C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
#7  0x00007ff8c3e58102 in KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk () from C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
#8  0x00007ff8c47bc264 in ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#9  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame inner to this frame (corrupt stack?)

Thread 17 (Thread 6352.0x504):
#0  0x00007ff8c4808404 in ntdll!ZwWaitForAlertByThreadId () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#1  0x00007ff8c47c7810 in ntdll!RtlSleepConditionVariableCS () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#2  0x00007ff8c0e2bb47 in SleepConditionVariableCS () from C:\Windows\system32\KernelBase.dll
#3  0x00007ff896f59420 in avfilter_graph_parse_ptr () from E:\Dev\Library\ffmpeg\bin\avfilter-6.dll
#4  0x00007ff896f5935f in avfilter_graph_parse_ptr () from E:\Dev\Library\ffmpeg\bin\avfilter-6.dll
#5  0x00007ff8c38ab097 in msvcrt!_beginthreadex () from C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
#6  0x00007ff8c38ab16c in msvcrt!_endthreadex () from C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
#7  0x00007ff8c3e58102 in KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk () from C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
#8  0x00007ff8c47bc264 in ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#9  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame inner to this frame (corrupt stack?)

Thread 16 (Thread 6352.0x12d0):
#0  0x00007ff8c4808404 in ntdll!ZwWaitForAlertByThreadId () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#1  0x00007ff8c47c7810 in ntdll!RtlSleepConditionVariableCS () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#2  0x00007ff8c0e2bb47 in SleepConditionVariableCS () from C:\Windows\system32\KernelBase.dll
#3  0x00007ff896f59420 in avfilter_graph_parse_ptr () from E:\Dev\Library\ffmpeg\bin\avfilter-6.dll
#4  0x00007ff896f5935f in avfilter_graph_parse_ptr () from E:\Dev\Library\ffmpeg\bin\avfilter-6.dll
#5  0x00007ff8c38ab097 in msvcrt!_beginthreadex () from C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
#6  0x00007ff8c38ab16c in msvcrt!_endthreadex () from C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
#7  0x00007ff8c3e58102 in KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk () from C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
#8  0x00007ff8c47bc264 in ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#9  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame inner to this frame (corrupt stack?)

Thread 15 (Thread 6352.0x7c8):
#0  0x00007ff8c4808404 in ntdll!ZwWaitForAlertByThreadId () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#1  0x00007ff8c47c7810 in ntdll!RtlSleepConditionVariableCS () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#2  0x00007ff8c0e2bb47 in SleepConditionVariableCS () from C:\Windows\system32\KernelBase.dll
#3  0x00007ff896f59420 in avfilter_graph_parse_ptr () from E:\Dev\Library\ffmpeg\bin\avfilter-6.dll
#4  0x00007ff896f5935f in avfilter_graph_parse_ptr () from E:\Dev\Library\ffmpeg\bin\avfilter-6.dll
#5  0x00007ff8c38ab097 in msvcrt!_beginthreadex () from C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
#6  0x00007ff8c38ab16c in msvcrt!_endthreadex () from C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
#7  0x00007ff8c3e58102 in KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk () from C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
#8  0x00007ff8c47bc264 in ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
#9  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame inner to this frame (corrupt stack?)

Thread 14 (Thread 6352.0xf08):
#0  0x00007ff8c4808404 in ntdll!ZwWaitForAlertByThreadId () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#1  0x00007ff8c47c7810 in ntdll!RtlSleepConditionVariableCS () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#2  0x00007ff8c0e2bb47 in SleepConditionVariableCS () from C:\Windows\system32\KernelBase.dll
#3  0x00007ff896f59420 in avfilter_graph_parse_ptr () from E:\Dev\Library\ffmpeg\bin\avfilter-6.dll
#4  0x00007ff896f5935f in avfilter_graph_parse_ptr () from E:\Dev\Library\ffmpeg\bin\avfilter-6.dll
#5  0x00007ff8c38ab097 in msvcrt!_beginthreadex () from C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
#6  0x00007ff8c38ab16c in msvcrt!_endthreadex () from C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
#7  0x00007ff8c3e58102 in KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk () from C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
#8  0x00007ff8c47bc264 in ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#9  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame inner to this frame (corrupt stack?)

Thread 13 (Thread 6352.0x1bb0):
#0  0x00007ff8c4808404 in ntdll!ZwWaitForAlertByThreadId () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#1  0x00007ff8c47c7810 in ntdll!RtlSleepConditionVariableCS () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#2  0x00007ff8c0e2bb47 in SleepConditionVariableCS () from C:\Windows\system32\KernelBase.dll
#3  0x00007ff896f59420 in avfilter_graph_parse_ptr () from E:\Dev\Library\ffmpeg\bin\avfilter-6.dll
#4  0x00007ff896f5935f in avfilter_graph_parse_ptr () from E:\Dev\Library\ffmpeg\bin\avfilter-6.dll
#5  0x00007ff8c38ab097 in msvcrt!_beginthreadex () from C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
#6  0x00007ff8c38ab16c in msvcrt!_endthreadex () from C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
#7  0x00007ff8c3e58102 in KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk () from C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
#8  0x00007ff8c47bc264 in ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#9  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame inner to this frame (corrupt stack?)

---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
Thread 12 (Thread 6352.0x1f14):
#0  0x00007ff8c4808404 in ntdll!ZwWaitForAlertByThreadId () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#1  0x00007ff8c47c7810 in ntdll!RtlSleepConditionVariableCS () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#2  0x00007ff8c0e2bb47 in SleepConditionVariableCS () from C:\Windows\system32\KernelBase.dll
#3  0x00007ff896f59420 in avfilter_graph_parse_ptr () from E:\Dev\Library\ffmpeg\bin\avfilter-6.dll
#4  0x00007ff896f5935f in avfilter_graph_parse_ptr () from E:\Dev\Library\ffmpeg\bin\avfilter-6.dll
#5  0x00007ff8c38ab097 in msvcrt!_beginthreadex () from C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
#6  0x00007ff8c38ab16c in msvcrt!_endthreadex () from C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
#7  0x00007ff8c3e58102 in KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk () from C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
#8  0x00007ff8c47bc264 in ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#9  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame inner to this frame (corrupt stack?)

Thread 11 (Thread 6352.0x1d00):
#0  0x00007ff8c4808404 in ntdll!ZwWaitForAlertByThreadId () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#1  0x00007ff8c47c7810 in ntdll!RtlSleepConditionVariableCS () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#2  0x00007ff8c0e2bb47 in SleepConditionVariableCS () from C:\Windows\system32\KernelBase.dll
#3  0x00007ff896f59420 in avfilter_graph_parse_ptr () from E:\Dev\Library\ffmpeg\bin\avfilter-6.dll
#4  0x00007ff896f5935f in avfilter_graph_parse_ptr () from E:\Dev\Library\ffmpeg\bin\avfilter-6.dll
#5  0x00007ff8c38ab097 in msvcrt!_beginthreadex () from C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
#6  0x00007ff8c38ab16c in msvcrt!_endthreadex () from C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
#7  0x00007ff8c3e58102 in KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk () from C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
#8  0x00007ff8c47bc264 in ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#9  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame inner to this frame (corrupt stack?)

Thread 10 (Thread 6352.0x544):
#0  0x00007ff8c4808404 in ntdll!ZwWaitForAlertByThreadId () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#1  0x00007ff8c47c7810 in ntdll!RtlSleepConditionVariableCS () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
#2  0x00007ff8c0e2bb47 in SleepConditionVariableCS () from C:\Windows\system32\KernelBase.dll
#3  0x00007ff896f59420 in avfilter_graph_parse_ptr () from E:\Dev\Library\ffmpeg\bin\avfilter-6.dll
#4  0x00007ff896f5935f in avfilter_graph_parse_ptr () from E:\Dev\Library\ffmpeg\bin\avfilter-6.dll
#5  0x00007ff8c38ab097 in msvcrt!_beginthreadex () from C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
#6  0x00007ff8c38ab16c in msvcrt!_endthreadex () from C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
#7  0x00007ff8c3e58102 in KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk () from C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
#8  0x00007ff8c47bc264 in ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#9  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame inner to this frame (corrupt stack?)

Thread 9 (Thread 6352.0xdac):
#0  0x00007ff8c48058a4 in ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#1  0x00007ff8c0e53b2f in WaitForMultipleObjectsEx () from C:\Windows\system32\KernelBase.dll
#2  0x00007ff8a2d4428b in ksproxy!DllUnregisterServer () from C:\Windows\System32\ksproxy.ax
#3  0x00007ff8c3e58102 in KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk () from C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
#4  0x00007ff8c47bc264 in ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#5  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame inner to this frame (corrupt stack?)

Thread 8 (Thread 6352.0x17b0):
#0  0x00007ff8c4804dd4 in ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#1  0x00007ff8c0e2aadf in WaitForSingleObjectEx () from C:\Windows\system32\KernelBase.dll
#2  0x00007ff8a2d5a8bb in ksproxy!KsResolveRequiredAttributes () from C:\Windows\System32\ksproxy.ax
#3  0x00007ff8c3e58102 in KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk () from C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
#4  0x00007ff8c47bc264 in ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#5  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame inner to this frame (corrupt stack?)

Thread 7 (Thread 6352.0x1f70):
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
#0  0x00007ff8c4804dd4 in ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#1  0x00007ff8c0e2aadf in WaitForSingleObjectEx () from C:\Windows\system32\KernelBase.dll
#2  0x00007ff896241b63 in ?? () from C:\Windows\System32\quartz.dll
#3  0x00007ff8c3e58102 in KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk () from C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
#4  0x00007ff8c47bc264 in ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#5  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame inner to this frame (corrupt stack?)

Thread 6 (Thread 6352.0x12fc):
#0  0x00007ff8c48058a4 in ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#1  0x00007ff8c0e53b2f in WaitForMultipleObjectsEx () from C:\Windows\system32\KernelBase.dll
#2  0x00007ff8c0e53a2e in WaitForMultipleObjects () from C:\Windows\system32\KernelBase.dll
#3  0x00007ff8a2d5b312 in ksproxy!KsResolveRequiredAttributes () from C:\Windows\System32\ksproxy.ax
#4  0x00007ff8c3e58102 in KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk () from C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
#5  0x00007ff8c47bc264 in ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#6  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame inner to this frame (corrupt stack?)

Thread 5 (Thread 6352.0x1e6c):
#0  0x00007ff8c32a1f74 in USER32!InvalidateRect () from C:\Windows\system32\user32.dll
#1  0x00007ff8c3292e15 in USER32!GetMessageW () from C:\Windows\system32\user32.dll
#2  0x00007ff89628ac1d in QUARTZ!AMGetErrorTextW () from C:\Windows\System32\quartz.dll
#3  0x00007ff8c3e58102 in KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk () from C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
#4  0x00007ff8c47bc264 in ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#5  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame inner to this frame (corrupt stack?)

Thread 4 (Thread 6352.0x1a7c):
#0  0x00007ff8c4808464 in ntdll!ZwWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
#1  0x00007ff8c478b2e8 in ntdll!RtlAcquireSRWLockShared () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#2  0x00007ff8c3e58102 in KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk () from C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
#3  0x00007ff8c47bc264 in ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#4  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame inner to this frame (corrupt stack?)

Thread 3 (Thread 6352.0x13b0):
#0  0x00007ff8c4808464 in ntdll!ZwWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#1  0x00007ff8c478b2e8 in ntdll!RtlAcquireSRWLockShared () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#2  0x00007ff8c3e58102 in KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk () from C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
#3  0x00007ff8c47bc264 in ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#4  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame inner to this frame (corrupt stack?)

Thread 2 (Thread 6352.0x214c):
#0  0x00007ff8c4808464 in ntdll!ZwWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#1  0x00007ff8c478b2e8 in ntdll!RtlAcquireSRWLockShared () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#2  0x00007ff8c3e58102 in KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk () from C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
#3  0x00007ff8c47bc264 in ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#4  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame inner to this frame (corrupt stack?)

Thread 1 (Thread 6352.0xc70):
#0  0x00007ff894fd08af in avpriv_mpegts_parse_close () from E:\Dev\Library\ffmpeg\bin\avformat-57.dll
#1  0x00007ff894fd499b in avformat-57!av_get_output_timestamp () from E:\Dev\Library\ffmpeg\bin\avformat-57.dll
#2  0x00007ff89502dbae in ff_rtsp_parse_line () from E:\Dev\Library\ffmpeg\bin\avformat-57.dll
#3  0x00007ff894fd3ded in avformat-57!av_interleaved_write_frame () from E:\Dev\Library\ffmpeg\bin\avformat-57.dll
#4  0x000000014001ab18 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame inner to this frame (corrupt stack?)
```

Comment: If you save to file does it crash?

Comment: No it doesn't. The crash happens when the connection is established.

Comment: gdb backtrace please?

Comment: I have appended the backtrace in the question post.

Comment: if you use ffmpeg_g.exe for the backtrace it might give you more info...

Comment: Is ffmpeg_g something that I have to build? I can only find ffmpeg.exe, ffplay.exe and ffprobe.exe.

Comment: Yeah you practically have to build it yourself (no distro's seem to include it). Here's one: https://sourceforge.net/projects/ffmpegwindowsbi/files/ffmpeg_g.exe/download

Comment: I tried again, and this time bt returns with a shorter message. There's no way but to build the ffmpeg library myself, is there...

Comment: `thread apply all bt` might help. You can compile your own: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide

Comment: Still trying to build. I think I need to get an older version of openssl according to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39344480/error-openssl-not-found-during-ffmpeg-configure

Comment: Finally. Successfully built ffmpeg with `--enable-debug` flag. Still unclear what's causing the crash...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved in a recent bug fix:

```
commit f8a13c72132a65e34e05b878dc780ad330dd7371
Author: Martin Storsjö <martin@martin.st>
Date:   Thu Sep 15 13:50:57 2016 +0200

    lavf/rtsp: Fix a crash with the RTSP muxer.

    Introduced in 00e122bc / bc2a3296
    The whole block that the statement was added to is only
    relevant when used as a demuxer, but the other statements
    there have had other if statements guarding them. Make
    sure to only run this whole block if being used as a
    demuxer.

    Fixes ticket #5844.
```

This solved it for me.

```
$ git checkout master
$ git pull
```